# Erro ao Enviar E-mail

Tags: laravel

Como faço para tratar esse erro ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse erro é quando eu tento enviar um e-mail pelo Localhost no Laravel.
OnLine funciona.

Mas tenho medo de que aconteça esse erro online também. 
Quero poder tratar; quando não for possível mandar o e-mail dar uma mensagem de erro.

Isso é possível ?

Tem que ser SMTP no Laravel e TSL.

Comment: Qual é a sua configuração de e-mail? O módulo SSL tá ativado? Posta o código aí.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30686838/3096922

Comment: Como está suas configurações do .ENV?

Comment: Está funcionando na Rede. Só quero tratar o problema.